# TypeError in Sweetalert2

Tags: angular, sweetalert

Can anyone tell me how it is that you have access to variables, functions in sweetalert2 is that at the moment I am unable to access anything gives this error.

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'wait' of undefined

My Code

```
swal({
  title: 'Editar '+ camponome,
  input: 'text',
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValue: campo,
}).then(function(text) {
  if (text) {
    swal({
      title: 'Aviso ',
      text: "Tem a certeza que deseja Editar",
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      cancelButtonText:'Cancelar',
      confirmButtonText: 'Sim Tenho '
      }).then(function() {
      this.wait=true;
    }) 
    }
})
```

**UPDATE Error on ng2-sweetalert2**

I installed ng2-sweetalert2 by npm and is giving me the following error

```
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-sweetalert2/ 404 (Not Found)
Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-sweetalert2(…)
```

I already put the settings in systemjs.config but it still does not work

My systemjs.config

```
var map = {
    'app':                        'dist', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-cookie':            'node_modules/angular2-cookie',  
    'ng2-sweetalert2':            'node_modules/ng2-sweetalert2',


  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-cookie':            {main: 'core.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'ng2-sweetalert2':            { defaultExtension: 'js' },

  };
```

My app.module

```
import { SweetAlertService } from 'ng2-sweetalert2';


enableProdMode();

const routes: Routes = [

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [...],       // module dependencies
  declarations: [...],   // components and directives
  entryComponents: [...],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],     // root component
  providers: [... , SweetAlertService],
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: How are you adding the sweetaler2 libraries to your project? Are you using ng2-sweetalert2? At the moment the function wait is not present on your window object. I assume you are not adding sweetalert to your angular2 project the right way.

Comment: I added the sweetalert in angular 2 this way was the only one that worked http://plnkr.co/edit/3WS18o7baXN1uegyuJCc?p=preview

Comment: I would try the ng2-sweetalert npm package. It's made for this

Comment: I have the package installed but it is giving me error

Comment: Maybe tell us the error so we can help? Can you update your question please?

Comment: Yes, I'll change already